# PhusionPassenger - 404 Resource Not Found (RestClient::ResourceNotFound)

Tags: passenger, rest-client

I am deploying my rails app on phusion passenger, now i need to use rhoconnect-rb gem to synchronize my data with Rhomobile app using Rhoconnect. 
I am getting this error:

Error message:

```
404 Resource Not Found (RestClient::ResourceNotFound)
```

Exception class:

```
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

How can i fix this?